# solve dell xps delay on touchpad and keyboard

Tags: touchpad, dell-xps

I finally found the complete solution for a frustrating/weird problem i was facing.

Problem A ) there is a touchpad delay when typing and try to use the touchpad?

problem B ) there is a 1 second delay when press any key and try to use left click button through touchpad?

pd: i make this because i searched a lot to get this solved and i want to share the solution, dont want any rep... my pc is a dell xps l521x, but im pretty sure it will apply for any xps model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution A ) no matter what touchpad manufacturer you are using, there is a setting named "smart sense" / "palm check" through driver settings that you should disable if want to delete this delay.

solution B ) there is a windows (( iam using windows 8.1 )) setting that you should disable: press WIN + W, then type "mouse", search for a option named "mouse and touch panel config", then search a setting related to touchpad delay and deactivate.

Comment: How do you access this smart sense setting? I have not been able to locate it through my driver settings. I'm also using windows 7.

Comment: @Klik go to control panel, select "mouse", search and select "Device Config" tab (( or something similar )), on the list displayed should exists at least one item, make double click on it and the synaptics clickpad config should appear, then make the changes :)